# Подскажите плагин Atom для языка JavaScript

Tags: javascript, atom, плагин

пишу код на JS в текстовом редакторе atom, иногда бывает, что забываю как правильно пишутся некоторые функции/методы (например Object.defineProperty и тд), так вот, хотел узнать есть ли плагин, который помог бы мне с "дописыванием" названий на JS, т.е я пишу Object.defi... а он подсказывает, что возможно я имел в виду Object.defineProperty, стоит плагин emmet, но это не то. Надеюсь на понимание и подходящий ответ)

Comment: взгляните https://codeforgeek.com/5-must-have-packages-atom-editor/

Comment: [Javascript Snippets](https://atom.io/packages/javascript-snippets)

Comment: [atom-ternjs](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs), в связке с [autocomplete-plus](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus)